# calling a dojo JsonRest with parameters

Tags: json, rest, dojo

When calling JsonRest using dojo, how can I pass parameters with it.

```
 var rest = new JsonRest({
                target: "/path/to/service"               
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonRest example:

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(JsonRest){
  // create a store with target your service
  var store = new JsonRest({
    target: "/path/to/service"
  });

  // make a get request passing some options
  store.query("foo=bar", {
    start: 5,
    count: 5,
    sort: [
      { attribute: "color", descending: true }
    ]
  }).then(function(results){
    // result here
  });
});
```

The function to use in your case is `query` with signature `query(query, options)`

When called, `query` will trigger a GET request to `{target}?{query}`, as described in [dojo docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.htm).

Please keep in mind that:

- If query is an object, it will be serialized.
- If query is a string, it is appended to the URL as-is.
- If options includes a sort property, it will be serialized as a query parameter as well;

Your service/API should:

- Return a array of objects in JSON format.
- Return an empty array if no match is found.